# Accessing to shared folders with OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

This is my first attempt to configure a vpn so I have very little knowledge about this.

Network where centos server is having local IPs 192.168.123.*

Network where windows machine is having local IPs 192.168.1.*

I installed and configured my openpvn server on centos 5 and client on a windows machine. Generated all keys, certificates e.t.c and transferred them to client and I'm able to connect to server. Below there is a screenshot of the client log.

Also on server side I can also see incoming packets with this command

tcpdump -n port 1723

So I assume I did most of the things correct.

But still when I try to open shared folders using \\192.168.123.33 or \\network-name I can't access folders

[image: openvpn client]

Edit:

And this is what I want to do and I'm not quite sure if I configured client and server config files correctly (routings or other stuff which I have no idea about).

[image]

Could you please guide me about config files and how should I do everything else.

Comment: Another this is on client in network connections I see a TAP-Win32 Adapter V9 network connection but it says cable unplugged. It seems this supposed to get an IP from remote network right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was because I was using certificates for both server and client generated by

```
./build-key-server
```

I missed that I have to use different certificates for clients generated using this command

```
./build-key
```

After I generated proper certificates and put to clients config folder, it connected.

Answer (score 1):

Do you can pinging 192.168.123.33?
Is sharing port(445) open on 192.168.123.33?
Dan you connect to sharing port on 192.168.123.33 with command:

```
telnet 192.168.123.33 445
```

Edit:

what is OpenVPN server IP Configuration(localip and remoteip range)?

Comment: No I can't ping. Please check also my new comment on my question

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a route on the 192.168.1.0 network advertising the route back to the 192.168.123.0 network?  Without it, the network traffic will be routed out the default gateway.

You can test this from a particular host by typing the following in a command window:

```
route ADD 192.168.123.0 MASK 255.255.255.0  192.168.0.999 <-LAN IP of CentOS box
```

This will temporarily add a route.  You can then try pinging that host from the VPN client.

Also, ip forwarding needs to be enabled on the CentOS box - http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/IPForwarding

Comment: I updated my question can you check it please because I'm not quite sure where to add that route line. thanks.

Comment: Can you post your server and client config files?